# What wire should I use to carry 12 V, 2 A power?

Tags: power, wiring, wire

I am working on wiring a 12 V, 2 A power supply to a DC linear actuator (both linked below), but I do not know what wire to use. Will 22 gauge wire work, or is there a different gauge or type to fit my use case? Thanks for any help.

Also, here is the [wire I think will work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D3MVRMR).

[Power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0711SZCMQ).

[Motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08H57PQTH).

Comment: 22awg is a bit skimpy, but could work. If it's enclosed and a long run, use 18 or 20. BTW: speaker wire is available in those gauges for a lot cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this [https://www.amazon.com/InstallGear-Gauge-Speaker-Touch-Cable/dp/B06W73MBD3/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=speaker+wire&qid=1624652266&refinements=p_85%3A2470955011&rnid=2470954011&rps=1&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06W73MBD3)

The motor is rated at 12V/3A so it's about a 4 Ohm load. 16 AWG wire has a resistance of about  13 mOhm/meter. If you have 2 meter long cables, that's a total of 4 meters or about 50 mOhm so you are only dropping 150 mV over the wires dissipating about 450mW in the process.

22AWG has about 4 times the resistance, so you add 200 mOhm, drop 600mV and dissipate 1.8W.

Comment: This will work perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to consider when selecting a wire: frequency, current, and voltage.

At higher frequencies the current will flow through the outside of the wire and not through the center. This means you have reason to use stranded wire over solid core and perhaps even a thicker wire than usual. Thankfully you are using DC so this is not critical, but keep this in mind for future projects. So use either solid core or stranded, whatever is easier for you (stranded is just easier to work with IMO).

Current dictates how thick (the gauge) the wire needs to be. For that look up your current in a table to tell you what gauge wire you need.

[image]

Since you are dealing with a 2A device that means 18AWG wire is the absolute thinnest you can safely use. So no 22 AWG wire will not be sufficient. Also keep in mind thinner wire adds some resistance, especially as it heats up. So usually better to use a thicket gauge than you would need. 18AWG is your minimum and thats fine but if you can go down to 16 AWG or more I would certainly recommend it.

It never hurts to calculate out the resistance just to see what is going on. So from our table if we pick the minimum thickness wire of 18AWG then the resistance is 0.13 Ohms per meter. Obviously at nearly 1/10th of an ohm that should not have any significant impact on driving your motor. Just keep in mind that the max current rating is basically only valid for reasonable length runs. As you can see if your trying anything unusual like running the wire for a kilometer then we might have a problem. But for normal run lengths just using the max current rating is more than sufficient as it isnt even close to a ohm worth of resistance.

Now just as current determines the thickness of the wire voltage determines the thickness of the insulator needed. Too thin and you get electrical arcs. Since you are only operating at 12V it is low enough that pretty much any insulated wire (aside from enamel insulation) should be more than sufficient. Just keep in mind when you work with higher voltages you will need to pay attention to the rating on the insulation itself.

Other thing i recommend, though not required, is to pick a wire with silicone insulation. They don't melt or shrink when you solder them so they are nice to work with. However they tend to cost a tad bit more so entirely optional.

Comment: I will be going with 16 gauge wire thanks to your help!

Comment: Yup, as I said, thicker is better. So 16 AWG is even better even if not strictly needed. Good luck!